# カルーセルページ内でのスクロール

Tags: onsen-ui

お世話になります。

ons-carousel-itemタグで複数のページを用意して横移動するようにしています。

このページの中に高さ固定で縦スクロール可能なDIVタグを埋め込んでいるのですが、
DIVタグ内で縦スクロールができずに、横移動しようとします。

解決方法がありましたら、教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 具体的なhtml,css,jsの抜粋があると回答しやすいかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Onsen-UI (version 1.2.1)では、下記の処理があるので、ons-carousel-item内で縦スクロールはできないですね。

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

ons-carouselの属性にdirection="horizontal"と入れてみたらどうでしょうか？